# Repository of SO-based academic papers

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, research

I'm a PhD student involved in [research](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128142/mining-information-from-stackoverflow-data) based on StackOverflow data. In doing so I am of course very interested in related work about SO.

However, there seems to be no centralised place where academic papers about SE/SO are listed, although [the community seems excited about the idea of SO-based academic research](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/academic-papers-using-stack-overflow-data/).

In addition to the afore-linked blog post (that mentions some papers from 2010), I found two other questions on meta ([one from 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71947/is-there-any-academic-research-going-on-regarding-stack-exchange) and [another one from 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105168/is-there-any-published-research-on-stack-overflow-in-the-last-18-months)) that also list a few papers.

However, this is IMO both hard to maintain as well as counter-intuitive. What I typically see for other data sources / tools is a separate section on their website where they list all publications that use their data. For example:

- [Qualitas Corpus](http://qualitascorpus.com/docs/publications/index.html) - a curated collection of software systems intended to be used for empirical studies of code artefacts;
- [Aprove](http://aprove.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/index.asp?subform=references.html) - an automated program verification environment;
- [ISBSG](http://www.isbsg.org/isbsgnew.nsf/WebPages/CC7EE413C6B3860DCA25747E004359B5?open) - a software development effort dataset.

What do you think about such a feature?

PS. I already have a list of new papers about SO (compiled using Google Scholar) waiting for the right place to be added.

**Update:** I have compiled a list of academic papers [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/academic-papers-using-stack-overflow-data).

Comment: Good idea. Why not make this question the repository?

Comment: I'm not sure if a question on meta would be the first place that comes to one's mind when searching for SO papers.

Comment: related (not a duplicate): [Gender, Representativeness and Reputation in Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139901/165773)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First,

[Stack Overflow is not a List of all Things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128561/140951)

However,

[Stack Overflow is not a perfect model of its guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128575/140951)

That said, if you *must* host something like this on Stack Overflow, **do not do it on the main site**.  If you *must* post it on one of the Stack Exchange sites, make sure to do the following:

- Post it on meta.  After all, this is a list of papers *about* Stack Overflow, so meta is the natural place to put this.
- Tag it with *at least* [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) and [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).
- Have *one* answer which you automatically accept.
- Make sure you have a *significant* answer to begin with.
- Be vigilant about maintaining it (for correctness, broken links, etc)

It's excessively difficult to get *all* of these things correct in order to maintain something like a book list, and failure to do *any* of them leads to closure and/or deletion rather quickly.

That said, I think the *best* option, however, would be to reach out to the community team with your information, and ask then to put an entry on the [Stack Exchange blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com) highlighting these items.  After all, they've posted about it before, and if there's significantly new and/or updated information then the blog is the perfect place to put it.

Comment: +1 for what StackOverflow is not.

Comment: How about making it a FAQ ?

Comment: @BogdanVasilescu Not on the main site, you aren't addressing an actual programming problem.  If it's going to be a FAQ then you do it here on meta, given the subject matter.  If you're talking about integrating it into the *actual* FAQ, *maybe* it could happen, but I doubt it, since the FAQ is for how to use the site, not anecdotes about it.

Comment: @casperOne the both links are, the same now **404** which is "Page not found" :) is there some other link? following this to get replies;
good answer too!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds interesting. For each paper one can, e.g., include the explicit reference to which version of the SO data has been used. In a longer run one can even envision sharing tools used to analyse the SO data.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a link to a curated bibliography or tag at http://researchr.org/ ?

They already have the infrastructure to link and collect publications.