# Is it a phishing?

Tags: discussion, security, third-party

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gender, Representativeness and Reputation in StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139901/gender-representativeness-and-reputation-in-stackoverflow)

I've seen an advertisement in one of developer communities to help a certain research.
When I went to a page, there's a questionnaire, and the required(*) fields were SO account ID and other sensitive info.
**WARNING: if you follow the page, don't enter your private information there unless this issue clarified!** here's the link: [Gender, Representativeness and Reputation in StackOverflow](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dEhtUVNQTEJmRTlwMVJSQ1hkeUZTR3c6MQ)

I just googled for the user profiles ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1528556/andrea-capiluppi), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1277111/alexander-serebrenik), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1285620/bogdan-vasilescu)) and it seemed these people have no relation to SO community. It's rather silly to be committed to a community participating there for only four days. :)

I found no relevant Q @Meta.

#### Questions

1. Are they anyhow affiliated with SO?
2. Is it safe to enter private info in conjunction with SO profile?
3. If it's a fraud, what steps SO community can take to prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those people have posted a request on Meta Stack Overflow asking for community input for a research of theirs. Here:

[Gender, Representativeness and Reputation in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139901/gender-representativeness-and-reputation-in-stackoverflow)